# Getting the height of a fixed shape within a rotating shape

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

So I have a box of dimensions length * height, and within that box I have a point which has arrows pointing to the top and bottom of the containing box.

[image: The basic box with point inside]

What I am trying to do is then rotate that box, but keep the direction of the arrow the same whilst continuing to fill the box from top to bottom at that coordinate.

[image: Rotation whilst keeping the point the same]

Because the direction of the arrow is stationary, as the box rotates the arrows from the point are going to get larger, with them being equal to the height of the box when at 0 degrees, and equal to the length of the box at 90 degrees.

I'm struggling however to find the length of the red arrow based upon the rotation of the box.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So the idea is, the red line will always stay vertical. And the rotation of the rectangle is characterized by its angle. So say, for example, that $\theta$ is the angle between the box and the vertical (like on the drawing below). [image]

But then, notice that if you draw the angle between the red line and the bottom side of your rectangle, then this angle will also be $\theta$. And you can argue that the blue little side $a$ has the same length as your original red line (do you see why this is true?)

Then, by trigonometry arguments, you can figure out the length of the red line :).

*Note: there are two choices of angles in this proof, but they are irrelevant. Instead, you could have defined $\theta$ as the angle between the box and the horizontal, and/or looked at another angle to figure out the red length.*

Comment: Thanks, but I feel like this is where I have been thrown and am missing something. When theta is 0 the red line should be equal to the length of the box. When theta is 90 it should be equal to the width of the box (a, in this example). So in this case the `length = sin (theta) * a` should be the length when theta is 1, but it is of course only 5.

Comment: The case $\theta = 90$ is fine, because $sin(90°) = 1$, so the length is exactly $a$. However, I am starting to think there might be a problem at $\theta = 0$, let me think about it

Comment: Yes, I do think the case $\theta = 0$ is a problem, and that my method is therefore wrong. It is correct in the case of the drawing (because $\theta$ is large enough), but as $\theta$ gets very small, it will end up connecting the two smallest sides of the rectangle, so we can't use the same trigonometry identity. (Another reason why this is obviously wrong is because according to the formula I gave, length(red line) should be $a/\sin\theta$, which is not defined at $0$. So that would mean the length of the red line is not continuous, which doesn't make sense).

Comment: I guess there is a way to bruteforce the problem, by just drawing the $\theta$ very small case, where the red line connects the two smallest sides, but it is very computational/not nice; so I think there might be a trick I am missing here, sorry, the problem has to have a nicer answer